# How do I find the list of bug fixes in each platform release of Salesforce.com?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Recently we are struggling after change made in SFDC platform which seems to be done as bug fixing.
Is there any place where I can find the list of bugs and fixes for them which was deployed into my environment.
Specifically we are having problem with point 13 described on this site (http://salesforceapexcodecorner.blogspot.com/2011/10/new-release-winter-12-in-apex.html):

> 1. String Conversion of Number Fields
>
> Previously, when String.valueOf was called with a field of type Number
>   of an sObject, it incorrectly treated the number field as a Decimal
>   when converting it to a String and used the String.valueOf(Decimal d)
>   method to perform the conversion to a String. Apex now correctly
>   converts a number field to a Double before performing the conversion
>   and uses the corresponding String.valueOf(Double d) method to convert
>   the Double value to a String. One side effect of this change is that
>   converted String values of number fields that have no decimal fraction
>   now have a decimal point (.0) in them where they didn't before.

Unfortunately I can't find any official info about this...

Thanks,
Łukasz

Answer (score 1):

The most extensive documentation of changes to the salesforce platform are in the release notes. Here are the [release notes for Winter 12 (v24)](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring12_release_notes.pdf), but you can just search the web for "[salesforce release notes](http://blekko.com/ws/salesforce+release+notes)" and you'll find what you're looking for.

If you are having trouble with a particular change that they've made, you should consider changing the version settings of the class or page in question back to the previous version that was working for you while you sort out the issue. You can change the version number from Setup > Develop > Classes > Version Settings.

If you would like help with the specific issue that you referenced, post more info about it and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Previously if You have used method string.valueOf on type Number of an sObject decimal fraction was not returned e.g. for value 5 string.valueOf() returned 5, now it's returning 5.0  I haven't find any official notes about this change.

Comment: If you want it to return 5, you can call String.valueof(Integer.valueof(number));

Comment: I know how I can fix this, what I don't know is why this change was made in first place and where to track such changes in future.

Comment: You can track the changes in the future by referring to the release notes that they put out in advance of the GA date of each new version. An example is above. The old behavior caused strange side effects with SelectOptions - this may have been the reason that they changed. Before the change, you had to cast a Decimal to a Double and then a String if you used it as the value in a SelectOption. Otherwise, the SelectList setter wouldn't get set correctly. I didn't see that explanation in the documentation, but that's my guess.

Comment: Thanks for trying but unfortunately this still doesn't resolve my main problem that I can't find any official note about this change.

Comment: You should post what your problem is.